# Resolution trouble

Tags: android

I have a device with resolution 800*480.
I create "Hello word" application. Then I get DisplayMetrics in onCreate of MainActivity.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
Log.d("Resolution", "resolution: " + metrics.widthPixels + " x " + metrics.heightPixels);
```

In DisplayMetrics there are 533*320 pixels. Why?

How can I make application for resolution 800*480 pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are reading `device independent pixels` not `real pixels`. These `dip` are equal to `mdpi` resolution. So despite real screen size, you should check what **density** it is (`mdpi` or `hdpi` or `xdpi`) and then put your hi-res assets in `-hdpi` suffixed folder (i.e. `drawable-hdpi` or `layout-hdpi`). Usually you set your layout in `dp` (so one layout XML file per activity usually suffices, and you should put them as usual in generic `res/layout` folder). and then put hi res drawables to make app look nicer on `hdpi` device

See [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing) for pixel-size and density relations...

Comment: **density** is 1.0, I put main.xls in layout-hdpi, but it the same.

Comment: `1.0` is base density which means mean `-mdpi` which means you cannot really do much. See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html if target lower than API 13. If API 13 is fine, then see screen size resource selectors. But I'd this - if phone says it is mdpi not hdpi live with it. See here too: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing for pixel-size-vs-density information...

Comment: ok... I should make different `layouts` and `graphics` for different resolution (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi)? How the system selects a resolution for my application? Why it not hdpi?

Comment: Usually no, just one layout file is usually perfectly fine (you usually do not need any real-screen-pixel precision so Android will handle your layout righ no matter of density). Adding  `-mdpi` (at least) and `-hdpi` graphic assets should also suffice at start.

Comment: I make `layout-mdpi`, `layout-hdpi`... place there two different layouts. Make `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`... place there PNG in different resolution. And now in application I see, that all images in `mdpi`, but one is `hdpi`. Do not understand...